# React Native FBSDK Version messed up for IOS and Android

Tags: react-native, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have an issue regarding FBSDK package version on IOS and Android.

For Android, if I used the latest 0.6.0 version there is an error saying:

> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
>
>   > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
>   >     '/Users/admin/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/26.0.0/aapt'' finished
>   >     with non-zero exit value 1

Now to sort this out I have to downgrade to 0.5.0 which works fine.

However in IOS, using the 0.5.0 version, I get an error saying:

> FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h not found

So I Have to bump it up to 0.6.0 to sort this out which is working. I do not know how to align this version out. Any advice is much appreciated thank you.

Comment: npm install react-native-fbsdk@0.6.0 --save to installl fbsdk react-native link fbsdk .Then update it using npm

Comment: @ParasWatts - same result, I linked it many time on android from settings.gradle, app/build.gradle, Main.Activity and MainApplication.java still got the same error.

Comment: I downgraded the FBSDK version to 0.5.1 which is now working on android but in IOS this error shows up: **Assignment to readonly property**.

Comment: Sorry I haven't yet worked on ios version, But android version with latest fbsdk is working fine on my side.

Comment: Maybe you can upload roject on github if possible and then i can try cloning it on my side and try to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Ok I will, be right back

Comment: wait, may I know what version of react native you are using? I am using 42.3 due to some packages I am using which breaks on newer version.

Comment: react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.40.0

Comment: It turns out that I am using lots of packages that works on 42.3 and 43.3 so my only option is to stick to my current RN version and modify the FBSDK code to make it work on both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally sorted out, I cloned the latest 0.6.1 version and modify the code so that it can work on RN0.43.3 on both android and ios.

Here are the steps:

1. After cloning/installing the latest version, go to your **node_modules/react-native-fbsdk/js**.
2. Open these files: FBLikeView.js, FBLoginButton.js,FBMessageDialog.js, FBSendButton.js, FBShareButton.js.
3. Change `import PropTypes from 'prop-types';` to `import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';`
4. Under react native import change `ViewPropTypes` to `View`.
5. Change `...ViewPropTypes,` to `...View.propTypes,`.
6. Save the changes and done.

Note: You have to do this in all 5 files you opened.

So far it works in my end perfectly.

This solves the issue about:

> 'LikeView' has no propType 'RCTFBLikeView.onLayout' of native type
>   'boolean' if you haven't changed this